# Device became slow after upgrade

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung

After upgrading to Jellybean(4.2) my device became slow. I have done several resets, but  still have the same problem. How do I go back to 4.1 or can this issue be fixed?

Comment: What is your phone's model?

Comment: Generally with Samsung you can't revert to an older version as their official OTA (over the air) updates include a new bootloader locked to the version of Android you just installed. What reset have you done? Factory? Are you using your SD card a lot, could that be the issue? What device is it?